# How would I broadcast a FTP website over WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, ftp, website, iis, broadcast

I am running a FTP site locally on Windows 8 x64. (The FTP site is local. I'm not hosting it or anything). I have configured IIS with a FTP Site at a certain IP address.

So how will I make users connect to that local FTP Site? I'm assuming WiFi. How do I accomplish this?

Currently I'm not on a WiFi network. I'm not ON ANY network for that matter of fact. I've configured the FTP server using IIS. I now want to **create** a WiFi network using the WiFi functionality of my laptop. Then I want hosts to connect to the WiFi that is being broadcasted (by my laptop), and then they can enter the FTP address to access the contents!

How would I let other users in the vicinity connect via WiFi to the local FTP site?

Comment: Once they connect to your wifi network, they will have access to the server.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: They can connect using the IP you have set up.

Comment: @Paul - I've provided a bit more clarity.

Comment: @terdon - Erm, please read the edit. I don't think that I was sufficiently informative before.

Comment: If the site is local you don't need FTP to access it, just browse to it on the local network.

Comment: Step 1: Put the IP address into an FTP client. Step 2: There is no step 2

Comment: @AbhishekSha There still isn't enough here to answer.  You have an FTP server on a wifi enabled network.  Once they connect to the wifi network, they can access the server.  What part of this do you need help with?

Comment: "I have configured the IIS with a FTP Site" -> Why IIS and not Apache? Actually, why the h*** you need a web server for? Just to display a link that users will click and open the FTP? Why not provide your users with the FTP address directly?

Comment: GUYS, I'm not ON a WiFi enabled network. I'm not ON ANY network for that matter of fact. I've configured the FTP using IIS. I now want to CREATE a WiFi network using the WiFi of my laptop and then I want hosts to connect to the WiFi that is being broadcasted (by my laptop) and then they can enter the FTP address to access the contents!

Comment: This seems a legitimate question though it might be better worded as "How to I create a local Wi-Fi network to share an FTP site". Lets give an answer?

Comment: Please rewrite you question as @JulianKnight suggested. It is a question about setting up a network and has nothing to do with your FTP server.

Answer (score 2):

If your IP address is 192.168.1.5, you can do like this:

**FTP access with a browser**

```
ftp://192.168.1.5
```

Address if you are using a non-standard port for FTP, lets say 9999:

```
ftp://192.168.1.5:9999
```

**FTP access with an FTP client (like FileZilla)**

Host: 192.168.1.5

Username: (none)

Password: (none)

Port: (no need to specify if you are using default port 21)